# What could cause implicit conversions on unreferenced columns in a join query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been wrecking my brain over this, I have a query that creates a plan with warnings about cardinality estimate wrong due to type conversion from `nvarchar` to `int`.

So I thought I'd take out all logic and try it that way

```
Select Top 100 * 
From table1
Inner Join table2 On table1.id = table2.foreignid
```

No conditionals, not specifying columns, nothing. The columns getting converted are not in any way referenced yet still get the plan warnings and a plan that reads 1 million rows from table1 to do this query.

What could cause SQL Server to decide to do implicit conversions on totally unreferenced columns?

Comment: You should include the error message you are getting.  My guess is that the id columns used for the joins have different types.

Comment: Both join on columns are straight int they aren't getting converted 

The two columns getting converted are not made reference to at all but give this 
<PlanEffectingConvert ConvertIssue"CardinalityEstimate" Expression="CONVERT(nvarchar(14), table2.SupplierID, 0)">

Another column with the same thing on the same table.

Comment: They are normally int before getting converted to nvarchar for whichever reason

Comment: Perhaps computed columns?

Comment: That was it. Definitely going to need to keep those on my radar as I go through the rest of these tables and sprocs.